# ipad uisplitviewcontroller in second view or fake uisplit

Tags: ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

My app should have a back end for the admin to change some settings, but in the back end view, I want to use a uisplitviewcontroller,

also the app only works in landscape mode,

the problem is that I have read the uisplitviewcontroller is only used in a root view scenario,

the other problem I noticed is that if I make a test app with uisplitviewcontroller (in root view) as in template, but put the app to only work on landscape mode, the right part of the uisplit doesnt show,,

so what to do? to accomplish a splitview kind of settings happening? (in second view)
* uisplitviewcontroller in a second view (how to make the landscape by default work??)
* uisplitviewcontroller faked with a table and loading views on the right side?? (how to do this??)

thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so, Im still customizing it,

but I ended up using this
[APSplitViewController – a custom SplitViewController](http://iphone-dev-tips.alterplay.com/2011/05/custom-uisplitviewcontroller-for-ipad.html#more)

thanks to the developer that this this